# Error in opening actvity from fragment through ListView using switch case

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I want to open activity from fragment by clicking on the ListView, but I am getting an error on the particular line. I have mentioned below
I have gone through many documentation, but none is working for me.

Any help would be great. Thank you!

```
public class ServicesFragment extends Fragment {


    ListView listView;
    String[] servicesNameArray;
    int[] serviceImages = {
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera};

    public ServicesFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.services_fragment, container, false);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        servicesNameArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.servicesName);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_services);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                int positionNew = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(position));
               int pos = (int) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(positionNew);//error in this line
                switch (pos) {

                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SlipActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;}}});

        ServicesAdapter adapter = new ServicesAdapter(this.getActivity(), servicesNameArray, serviceImages);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    public class ServicesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context c;
        int[] servicesImageArray;
        String[] servicesNameArray;
 public ServicesAdapter(Context context, String[] servicesNameArray, int[] serviceImages) {
            super(context, R.layout.services_layout, R.id.listView_services, servicesNameArray);
            Log.d("ashu", "adapter called");
            this.c = context;
            this.servicesImageArray = serviceImages;
            this.servicesNameArray = servicesNameArray;}}}
```

Logcat:

```
          java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
              at com.bulletin.theinvincible.nautical.ServicesFragment$1.onItemClick(ServicesFragment.java:73)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: i have pasted my logcat error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition(int))

> `Object getItemAtPosition (int position)` : Gets the data associated with
>   the specified position in the list.

If you want to start new activity based on listview position. You can simply try:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

         switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SlipActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
        }
});
```